# "Should be completed until you will have arrived" - doesn't it sound weird?

Tags: exam-questions

A question from an online English level test (https://antischool.online/cabinet/online-test/?utm_source=youtube&utm_medium=social-organic&utm_campaign=test&utm_content=ariz&utm_term=levels-01.06.21):

№9 -Online check-in should be ______(11) until you will ____ (12) at the airport so you'll chose the best seats.

-Of course! Thanks for your help!

Answers:

A. complete; have arived

B. completed; arrive

C. completed; have arrived (seems to be the intended answer, because when it's changed, points are lost)

Is this sentence grammatically correct? What is the meaning of this sentence? Which answer is correct?

P.s. A free online lesson is offered to those who finish the test)))

Comment: In my opinion, it's completely wrong. It should probably read "Online check-in should be **completed before your arrive** at the airport so [that] you **can choose** the best seats."

Comment: I agree with @JavaLatte (although I think you mean "before **you** arrive").  As the sentence is written, I can't see any correct way to complete it.  Online check-in should be *something* **until** *something else*?  The only kind of verb I can see fitting in there would be something like *defer*.

Comment: I think a free online lesson from that group would be a really bad idea.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty Well, it is called antischool. Perhaps the  clue is in the name! :D

Comment: Looks like the comments answer my question